# Playback And Recording simultaneously on Corona SDK

Tags: iphone, ipad, lua, coronasdk

How can i playback and record simultaneously using Corona SDK for iOS devices? I am trying to build something similar to karaoke. It would be helpful if someone pointed me to any ready API or repository on GitHub or could help me solve the problem.

Comment: I do not understood, you want to play what you are saying on the microphone (very hard to do) or just play a sound while the microphone is active at the same time? (I believe that then it is not that hard)

Comment: @speeder for example music is playing, and user is singing, and output sound files is saved by combining music and the user's singing. just like any karaoke app. you can google karaoke to get a more clear idea of what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you cannot do that in realtime...

And to do without realtime would involve using some APIs that Corona do not expose to do sound editing, Corona support for sound is still VERY basic, probably because Android sound support is a little unstable now too...

To do that you would need Corona Enterprise, and lots of native SDK fiddling, and I am not sure if you can do it in Android without some heavy work...

Comment: I have Corona Enterprise License. I am facing the same problem.. Could you point out the controls in Corona which I should refer, to get this working.

Comment: + 1 @VimalVenugopalan or the API's with which it's possible to achieve this.